# Tkinter Entry conditional sentence question

Tags: python, tkinter

It hasn't been long since I learned Python.
Recently, I've been studying Tkinter mode.
I'm making a food recommendation program, but I don't know how to write a conditional sentence, so I ask questions.
What I want to make is a program in which one of the breakfast lists appears randomly in entry next to entry 1 when you type the word "breakfast" in entry 1 and press the buttons next to it.
picture is my program.
and this is my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQKoB.png)

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def K_list():
    ent2.delete(0,END)
    M_k_menu = ["순대국밥", "콩나물국밥", "김치찌개", "된장찌개", "컵라면"]
    L_K_menu = ["김밥", "라면", "떡복이", "라볶이", "냉면", "백반"]
    D_K_menu = ["족발", "치킨", "곱창", "삼겹살", "감자탕", "칼국수"]

    Mfood = "아침"
    Lfood = "점심"
    Dfood = "저녁"

    if Mfood == "아침":
        Mfood = ent1.get()
        M_k_menu = random.choice(M_k_menu)
        ent2.insert(0,M_k_menu)

    elif Lfood == "점심":
         Lfood = ent1.get()
         L_k_menu = random.choice(L_k_menu)
         ent2.insert(0,L_k_menu)

    elif Dfood == "저녁":
        Dfood = ent1.get()
        D_k_menu = random.choice(D_k_menu)
        ent2.insert(0,D_k_menu)

    else :
        print("잘못 입력 하였습니다")
        
          
def delete():
    ent1.delete(0,END)
    ent2.delete(0,END)
    ent3.delete(0,END)
    ent4.delete(0,END)
    ent5.delete(0,END)
    ent6.delete(0,END)
```